# ImportError: No module named jabber:python

Tags: python, xmpp

I have installed python jabber package from this url
http://sourceforge.net/projects/jabberpy/files/

But when i am importing i am still getting the following error.

```
>>> import jabber
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named jabber
```

i am using python 2.7.5, jabberpy 0.5
How to overcome this..? Thanks in advance

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: @jsalonen, i downloaded it and installed as `python setup.py install`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jabberpy 0.5 does not include `__init__.py` file and as such, is not detected as a [package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910379/importing-modules-in-python-and-init-py). I don't know why that is take case. My guess is that earlier versions of Python `__init__.py` was not required, which would explain why its not included in jabberpy.

You can work around this problem by manually creating empty `__init__.py` file under the location your module install (probably something like `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jabber`)

If you don't want to touch the jabberpy module, you can also include the install location of your module before loading it:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jabber')

import jabber
```

Both of the workarounds are ugly. I would just probably take a look at [alternative, fresher Jabber libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901828/best-python-xmpp-jabber-client-library) that don't have this problem in the first place.

Comment: jsalonen, I am using fedora 20, and i downloaded the last version of jabber that is 0.5

Comment: Edited the answer to use Linux paths. I know you are using latest jabberpy. What I'm saying is that you should use some other library instead.

Comment: @Mulagala: it depends on where you have installed Python and which is the site-packages folder you are installing your module into. Just locate the module and change the path accordingly :)